# Firebase Real Time Chat in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to integrate Firebase Real Time Chat in our iOS Application. But, at web side our server works with XMPP on web. Is it possible to have both XMPP and FCM for one server for chat purpose i.e., I will use FCM in android/iOS while, XMPP at Web Server.

Comment: I don't think so, XMPP has different architecture and paradigm than FCM. There would be a bridge needed b/w both, that might take a lot of good effort and its overkill. You need to choose one.

Comment: Ohk, means I have to go with XMPP in mobile apps also.

Comment: Yes, XMPP is desirable in your case, since its already there on web.

Comment: Thanks..Actually I have to build only XMPP Client for the shake of web server in iOS. Thanks.

Comment: HI Adil, One more thing I want to know. if my server simply use http in chat application, then can we use FCM in this case.I explored a bit, I came to know that FCM client used to send message to FCM and FCM push messages to Server. If possible then give me some good help. Thanks

Comment: How are the messages stored on your http chat app? If they're stored on your server-hosted database, in that case you need to add a bridge (mechanism) either on your web chat app to send the same message to FCM and to your server-hosted db, or on your mobile apps to save a message to FCM as well as to server-hosted database.